# How to get the ODBC name from this trace logs that an application is using to connect

Tags: windows, odbc, firebird

How to get the ODBC name from this trace logs that an application is using to connect (in this case: a Firebird database)

```
AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLAllocEnv 
        HENV *              0x5D67B1AC

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLAllocEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV *              0x5D67B1AC ( 0x02E61078)

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLGetEnvAttr 
        SQLHENV             0x02E61078
        SQLINTEGER                 201 <SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING>
        SQLPOINTER          0x0012EA64
        SQLINTEGER                   4 
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0012EA60

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLGetEnvAttr  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHENV             0x02E61078
        SQLINTEGER                 201 <SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING>
        SQLPOINTER          0x0012EA64 (0) <SQL_CP_OFF>
        SQLINTEGER                   4 
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0012EA60 (0)

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLAllocEnv 
        HENV *              0x5D67B1B0

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLAllocEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV *              0x5D67B1B0 ( 0x02E610F0)

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLSetEnvAttr 
        SQLHENV             0x02E610F0
        SQLINTEGER                 201 <SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING>
        SQLPOINTER                 0 <SQL_CP_OFF>
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLSetEnvAttr  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHENV             0x02E610F0
        SQLINTEGER                 201 <SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING>
        SQLPOINTER                 0 <SQL_CP_OFF>
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLAllocConnect 
        HENV                0x02E610F0
        HDBC *              0x0012F6F0

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLAllocConnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                0x02E610F0
        HDBC *              0x0012F6F0 ( 0x02E61388)

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLGetInfoW 
        HDBC                0x02E61388
        UWORD                       10 <SQL_ODBC_VER>
        PTR                 0x0012F6C0 
        SWORD                       22 
        SWORD *             0x00000000

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLGetInfoW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HDBC                0x02E61388
        UWORD                       10 <SQL_ODBC_VER>
        PTR                 0x0012F6C0 [      -3] "03.80.0000\ 0"
        SWORD                       22 
        SWORD *             0x00000000

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLSetConnectAttrW 
        SQLHDBC             0x02E61388
        SQLINTEGER                 103 <SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT>
        SQLPOINTER                15
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLSetConnectAttrW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHDBC             0x02E61388
        SQLINTEGER                 103 <SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT>
        SQLPOINTER                15
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLDriverConnectW 
        HDBC                0x02E61388
        HWND                0x00000000
        WCHAR *             0x6D5F8B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x6D5F8B34 
        SWORD                       -3 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HDBC                0x02E61388
        HWND                0x00000000
        WCHAR *             0x6D5F8B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x6D5F8B34 
        SWORD                       -3 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

        DIAG [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) 

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW 
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
        SQLHANDLE           0x02E61388
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F654
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0012F22C
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F254 
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0012F23C

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
        SQLHANDLE           0x02E61388
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F654 [       5] "IM002"
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0012F22C (0)
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F254 [      91] "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0012F23C (91)

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW 
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
        SQLHANDLE           0x02E61388
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F654
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0012F22C
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F254 
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0012F23C

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
        SQLHANDLE           0x02E61388
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F654
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0012F22C
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F254 
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0012F23C

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLFreeConnect 
        HDBC                0x02E61388

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLFreeConnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HDBC                0x02E61388

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLFreeEnv 
        HENV                0x02E61078

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLFreeEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                0x02E61078

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   ENTER SQLFreeEnv 
        HENV                0x02E610F0

AutoReps        1f8c-140c   EXIT  SQLFreeEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                0x02E610F0

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLAllocEnv 
        HENV *              0x5D67B1AC

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLAllocEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV *              0x5D67B1AC ( 0x02E61E60)

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLGetEnvAttr 
        SQLHENV             0x02E61E60
        SQLINTEGER                 201 <SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING>
        SQLPOINTER          0x0012EA64
        SQLINTEGER                   4 
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0012EA60

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLGetEnvAttr  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHENV             0x02E61E60
        SQLINTEGER                 201 <SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING>
        SQLPOINTER          0x0012EA64 (0) <SQL_CP_OFF>
        SQLINTEGER                   4 
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0012EA60 (0)

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLAllocEnv 
        HENV *              0x5D67B1B0

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLAllocEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV *              0x5D67B1B0 ( 0x02E61ED8)

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLSetEnvAttr 
        SQLHENV             0x02E61ED8
        SQLINTEGER                 201 <SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING>
        SQLPOINTER                 0 <SQL_CP_OFF>
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLSetEnvAttr  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHENV             0x02E61ED8
        SQLINTEGER                 201 <SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING>
        SQLPOINTER                 0 <SQL_CP_OFF>
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLAllocConnect 
        HENV                0x02E61ED8
        HDBC *              0x0012F6F0

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLAllocConnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                0x02E61ED8
        HDBC *              0x0012F6F0 ( 0x002493F0)

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLGetInfoW 
        HDBC                0x002493F0
        UWORD                       10 <SQL_ODBC_VER>
        PTR                 0x0012F6C0 
        SWORD                       22 
        SWORD *             0x00000000

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLGetInfoW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HDBC                0x002493F0
        UWORD                       10 <SQL_ODBC_VER>
        PTR                 0x0012F6C0 [      -3] "03.80.0000\ 0"
        SWORD                       22 
        SWORD *             0x00000000

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLSetConnectAttrW 
        SQLHDBC             0x002493F0
        SQLINTEGER                 103 <SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT>
        SQLPOINTER                15
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLSetConnectAttrW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHDBC             0x002493F0
        SQLINTEGER                 103 <SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT>
        SQLPOINTER                15
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLDriverConnectW 
        HDBC                0x002493F0
        HWND                0x00000000
        WCHAR *             0x6D5F8B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x6D5F8B34 
        SWORD                       -3 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HDBC                0x002493F0
        HWND                0x00000000
        WCHAR *             0x6D5F8B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x6D5F8B34 
        SWORD                       -3 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

        DIAG [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) 

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW 
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
        SQLHANDLE           0x002493F0
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F654
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0012F22C
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F254 
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0012F23C

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
        SQLHANDLE           0x002493F0
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F654 [       5] "IM002"
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0012F22C (0)
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F254 [      91] "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0012F23C (91)

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW 
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
        SQLHANDLE           0x002493F0
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F654
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0012F22C
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F254 
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0012F23C

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
        SQLHANDLE           0x002493F0
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F654
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0012F22C
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0012F254 
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0012F23C

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLFreeConnect 
        HDBC                0x002493F0

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLFreeConnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HDBC                0x002493F0

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLFreeEnv 
        HENV                0x02E61E60

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLFreeEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                0x02E61E60

AutoReps        1214-5e8    ENTER SQLFreeEnv 
        HENV                0x02E61ED8

AutoReps        1214-5e8    EXIT  SQLFreeEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                0x02E61ED8
```

Comment: As far as I read this log, it isn't connecting to Firebird at all, because it can't find the data source name. Also looking at the documentation of [SQLDriverConnect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you are using the connection string `"******\ 0"`, which I assume is some anonymization.

Comment: Thank you for the response Mark. I am a tech support guy. The developer of the application had code the ODBC DNS name. This is what I am trying to figure out so that I can set this name my profile that is connecting.

Comment: Thank you for the response Mark. I am a tech support guy. The developer of the application hard coded the ODBC DNS name. This is what I am trying to figure out so that I can set this name in my profile that is connecting.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean with "ODBC name"... Do you mean target database user-name? However, SQLDriverConnect[W] has the following syntax:

```
SQLRETURN SQLDriverConnect(
 SQLHDBC         ConnectionHandle,
 SQLHWND         WindowHandle,
 SQLCHAR *       InConnectionString,
 SQLSMALLINT     StringLength1,
 SQLCHAR *       OutConnectionString,
 SQLSMALLINT     BufferLength,
 SQLSMALLINT *   StringLength2Ptr,
 SQLUSMALLINT    DriverCompletion);
```

By reading your trace it looks like "InConnectionString" is ""******\ 0". They're probably trying to mask it because connection string includes the password. The length of the InConnectionString (subsequent field) is -3 which means: NULL terminated.

The error says that their connection string contains a wrong DSN

Comment: Mauro, Thanks for the reply. Yes I am was actually checking if I could see what DSN the app is seeking so that I can rename the on on the server to that. If is actually masked then I guess I am not in luck.